# Getting the value of an img

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, ajax

I am not sure if you can do this, but if not please provide me with a simple work around if possible.  I am want the user to select an img (id of 'cowboys' or 'giants').  I want to get the value of these (which are both 'One') and return that into the id 'scenario'.  Everything else works except this part and I have a feeling it is bc you can't do it.  So any suggestions would be depreciated!

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //this is the user id session stored as a javascript variable
        var userid = "<?=$id?>";

        function bigimg(x) {
            var myDate = new Date(); // Your timezone! 
            var myEpoch = myDate.getTime()/1000; 
            var deadline = '1344700055.000'; 
                //determines if user was on time..if not on time hover enlarge won't work
                if(myEpoch < deadline) {
                    x.style.height="65px";
                    x.style.width="85px";
                    x.style.opacity="0.5";
                } else {}
        }
        function defaultimg(x) {
            x.style.height="60px";
            x.style.width="80px";
            x.style.opacity="1.0";
        }
        function teamback(x) {
            var myDate = new Date(); // Your timezone! 
            var myEpoch = myDate.getTime()/1000; 
            var deadline = '1344700055.000';
                //determines if user was on time..if not on time submitting won't work
                if(myEpoch > deadline) {
                    // update the "actualone" image's source to the sending-image's source
                    document.getElementById("actualone").src = x.src;
                    document.getElementById("curtime").innerHTML = myEpoch;
                    document.getElementById("team").innerHTML = x.id;
                    document.getElementById("team").innerHTML = x.value;
                } else {}           
        }
        </script>

    </head>
        <body>
            Your Team<br>
            <iframe style="background-color:red;" src="http://free.timeanddate.com/countdown/i38ik9yz/n417/cf12/cm0/cu4/ct1/cs1/ca0/co1/cr0/ss0/cac000/cpc000/pct/tc66c/fs100/szw320/szh135/tatTime%20Remaining%20to%20Make%20Picks/tac000/tptTime%20since%20Event%20started%20in/tpc000/iso2012-08-11T13:00:00" frameborder="0" width="236" height="36"></iframe>

            <br><img id="cowboys" value="One" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this)" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="cowboys.gif"> vs <img id="giants" value="One" onmouseover="bigimg(this)" onclick="teamback(this)" onmouseout="defaultimg(this)" src="giants.gif"><img src="" id="actualone" style="width:85px; height:65px;"><br><br>
            <img src="colts.gif"> vs <img src="bears.gif">
            <div id="curtime">44</div>|||<div id="deadline"></div><br><div id="team">Team</div><div id="scenario">Scenario</div>


        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It isn't entirely clear what you are asking.  Can you narrow down your example to a small snippet of what you are trying to do?  "value of an image" isn't all that meaningful.  Do you mean raw image data?  Image name or URL?  Also, you really should be escaping your data when used in queries.  At best, you will come across errors in your SQL from time to time, and at worst you will be opening up SQL injection vulnerabilities.  I recommend learning to use prepared queries with PDO.

Comment: Where is scenario? You have two team:                     document.getElementById("team").innerHTML = x.id;
                    document.getElementById("team").innerHTML = x.value;

Comment: `I want to get the value of these (which are both 'One').` What do you mean by VALUE of IMAGES?

Comment: Asker has a `value` tag set on the `img` elements themselves: `<img id="cowboys" value="One"`, which isn't exactly valid markup. Why do you need to get the value? Why did you set `value` to the same for both images? Why do you assign `#team` both `x.id` and `x.value`?

Comment: I mean that I have set the value="One" for both of them..

Comment: thanks for the help the guy below solved it.  thankx!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`value` is an attribute that can only be applied to form elements, like `input`. If you want to get a simple attribute, use `name`.

Comment: ***data-**** attributes are useful. You can set any needed values using them like <img data-name="Linus" data-surname="Torvalds" src="img/linus.png" /> and then retrieve them like img.getAttribute('data-surname')

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
document.getElementById("team").innerHTML = x.id;
document.getElementById("team").innerHTML = x.value;
```

to

```
document.getElementById("team").innerHTML = x.id;
document.getElementById("scenario").innerHTML = x.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [expando](http://madskristensen.net/post/The-expando-attribute.aspx) attribute so you can add custom attributes like 'value' and read it using JavaScript/jQuery.